# database error 1054 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I am trying to do an OTH application and i am getting this error

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT `data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE `id` =
>   'dd8fddaabb45c365fbf27a6fdc5ea60d59f569e4' AND `ip_address` = '::1'
>
> Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 160

This is Session_database_driver.php

```
public function read($session_id) {
        if ($this->_get_lock($session_id) !== FALSE)
        {
            // Needed by write() to detect session_regenerate_id() calls
            $this->_session_id = $session_id;

            $this->_db
                ->select('data')
                ->from($this->_config['save_path'])
                ->where('id', $session_id);

            if ($this->_config['match_ip'])
            {
                $this->_db->where('ip_address', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            }

            if (($result = $this->_db->get()->row()) === NULL)
            {
                $this->_fingerprint = md5('');
                return '';
            }

            // PostgreSQL's variant of a BLOB datatype is Bytea, which is a
            // PITA to work with, so we use base64-encoded data in a TEXT
            // field instead.
            $result = ($this->_platform === 'postgre')
                ? base64_decode(rtrim($result->data))
                : $result->data;

            $this->_fingerprint = md5($result);
            $this->_row_exists = TRUE;
            return $result;
        }

        $this->_fingerprint = md5('');
        return '';
}
```

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960544/codeigniter-error-session-db ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I tried that but its not working. Actually over there some table name missing problem was there.

Comment: If you change `select('data')` to `select('user_data')` what happens?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

SELECT `user_data` FROM `ci_sessions` WHERE `id` = '0c37a2a2094055181b386efea510a21068d71e4d' AND `ip_address` = '::1'

Comment: I think I understand the problem

Comment: Take a look at the answer i posted. Do you still getting errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to CI manual regarding [`Sessions`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) the basic format 
of the `ci_sessions` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

In your php code you're using different fields:

```
$this->_db
                ->select('data')
                ->from($this->_config['save_path'])
                ->where('id', $session_id);
```

So, by altering that code to:

```
$this->_db
                ->select('user_data')
                ->from($this->_config['save_path'])
                ->where('session_id', $session_id);
```

Your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right solution is to check if your DB is correctly created.

According to [Documentation for CI 3.0.0](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions) the correct database would be:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

I dont agree on changing CI drivers files

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, i already changed...

```
$this->_db
                ->select('data')
                ->from($this->_config['save_path'])
                ->where('id', $session_id);
```

to ->>>>>

```
$this->_db
                ->select('user_data')
                ->from($this->_config['save_path'])
                ->where('session_id', $session_id);
```

the problem will exist if i do this in my config.ph

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Comment: oh miss the..->where('id', $session_id);  changed some fields like "user_data" and "session_id" and ...it works...