# codeigniter Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have errors in CI

```
Error Number: 2006

MySQL server has gone away

UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `timestamp` = 1475160630 WHERE `id` = 'a0ee72450a40e6e030aa1f3c5b6e2db8b6efc2cf'

Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 243
```

and

Error Number: 2006

```
MySQL server has gone away

SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('a0ee72450a40e6e030aa1f3c5b6e2db8b6efc2cf') AS ci_session_lock

Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 367
```

I googled for solutions and find answer here

[Codeigniter error session DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960544/codeigniter-error-session-db)

[Codeigniter error session DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960544/codeigniter-error-session-db/29459563)

but above solution didnot worked for my problem.

here is my config.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = "";

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = '';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

$config['language'] = 'english';

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';


$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';


$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

$config['log_threshold'] = 0;


$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['log_file_extension'] = '';


$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;

$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$config['error_views_path'] = '';

$config['cache_path'] = '';


$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;

$config['encryption_key'] = '';


$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem once i solve it by editing the config file
please try this

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 86400;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: thanks Jithin Kuriakose for you answer but above answer did not work for my problem i also share my config.php .Please help me

Comment: try this it would done the trick. Here it save as file inside of database

Comment: Great to heard that.